# Answerers Should not be able to vote/comment on other Answers to the same question

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

Why are answerers allowed to comment/vote on one another's posts? We can infer that answerer's already disagree with one another which is why they wrote their own answer. Or they wanted to contribute to the other answerer.

It seems answerers think their own answer is better and will downvote other answers just because they want their own answer to be the best.

If an answerer wants to respond to another's answer they could do it in their own answer (ie "Other answerers have said X but I believe Y").

**This is not a duplicate. Other questions ask about etiquette. I am asking why it still exists.**

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42871/should-we-stop-people-voting-on-answers-when-they-have-a-competing-answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129304/is-it-good-practice-to-refrain-from-downvoting-competing-answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175241/is-it-bad-etiquette-to-downvote-a-competing-answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28777/disallow-downvoting-other-answers-if-ive-posted-my-own http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98643/is-it-common-for-people-to-down-vote-because-they-have-a-competing-answer

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/119/sportsmanship

Comment: @random not a duplicate

Comment: @mmyers So 1 badge vs. the hundreds you can get for having the best answer which snowballs into tens of upvotes

Comment: Why don't they? Answerers are considered having knowledge on their field, why can't they comment/criticize/feedback other answers? As for answerer downvoting others for their own benefit, I almost never see it, and if it happens (and if I have concrete proof, since I can't even know who votes what), I can **flag it for moderator intervention**. Lastly, you can comment on your answer mentioning your opinion about other answer, but what does it achieve? Oh, and "*all roads lead to Rome*" (there are multiple solutions to a problem)

Comment: But really, "downvoting answer just for their personal benefit" is one of the least problem on here, and if your request is implemented, the disadvantage is bigger than the advantage.

Answer (score 8):

> We can infer that answerer's already disagree with one another

No, we can't. Giving a different answer doesn't mean one thinks all other answers are bad/wrong/incorrect. Possibly incomplete, but that's the only inference I would comfortably make.

> It seems answerers think their own answer is better and will downvote other answers just because they want their own answer to be the best.

You'd think. But that doesn't happen. Mostly due to the 1 rep penalty for downvoting an answer.

> If an answerer wants to respond to another's answer they could do it in their own answer

That's what comments are for.

---

As for the meat of your question:

> Why are answerers allowed to comment/vote on one another's posts?

1. There is no good reason not to. The scenarios you have raised turn out to be non issues. They don't happen (or rarely happen).
2. People who answer tend to be those who are knowledgeable in the field they are answering on. Pointing out inaccuracies, bad practices and just incorrect information is beneficial to everyone. Blocking these things is not. These should be done in comments and not in "rival" answers, as this is the point of comments. Answers should not be places where one just points out issues in other answers - that just detracts from an answer.

So - there is no real upside to blocking answerers from responding to other answers and a real downside to it.

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question. Why are answerers allowed to comment/vote on one another's posts? What benefits?

Comment: @SethKitchen: the benefits of comments & voting for "competing" answers are exactly the same as for any other post.